# Who were Cassian and Jyn supposed to meet in Jedha City?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, rogue-one

In *Rogue One*, Cassian and Jyn went to Jedha in order to meet someone who could take them to Saw Gerrera.

> **Cassian:** I had a contact, one of Saw's Rebels. But he's just gone
>   missing. His sister will be looking for him. The temple's been
>   destroyed, but she'll be there waiting. We'll give her your name and
>   hope that gets us a meeting with Saw.

They never got a chance to meet her, before the Gerrera's gang found them. She probably wasn't at the headquarters either; all of the gangmembers seemed to be males, and no one approached Cassian during his captivity. So, who was she, why would she stay at the temple, and what happened to her (and her brother)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as we're aware, the only direct contact Cassian had in Saw's gang was Tivik, [the man that he shot on the Ring of Kafrene to keep from falling into the Empire's hands](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152751/why-did-cassian-andor-kill-that-person/152752#152752). He presumably reached out to [Tivik's sister](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tivik%27s_sister) (without explaining that he was the one responsible for his <s>murder</s> unexplained disappearance) knowing that she'd be worried about his absence and hence be more susceptible to an approach from Cassian.

As to her fate, that remains unknown but since we know that she was near the Jedi Temple at Jedha just a few hours before the weapons test of the Death Star, it's reasonably likely that she died along with the other pilgrims and traders.

Comment: unless she hitched as equally an unlikely ride as Dr. Evazan and Ponda Baba

Comment: @NKCampbell - Well, indeed.